# Mysql search query two columns

Tags: mysql, search

I'm bulding a search function for my web site and wish to search by two columns: title and author.

Query:

```
SELECT title, bookID, publisher, pubDate, book_image, books.authorID, authors.author FROM books, authors WHERE books.authorID = authors.authorID 
            AND title LIKE '$queryString%' OR author LIKE '$queryString%'LIMIT 5
```

When I search by title this works fine, but when I search by author I get a list of all books with the searched for author as author. Obviously this is incorrect.

How can I fix this query to successfully search for either title or author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below :

```
SELECT title, bookID, publisher, pubDate, book_image, books.authorID, authors.author 
FROM books left join  authors on  books.authorID = authors.authorID 
WHERE (title LIKE '$queryString%' OR author LIKE '$queryString%') LIMIT 5
```

I would like to suggest you to use [**fulltext**](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm) search in mysql.That will be more faster and efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, bookID, publisher, pubDate, book_image, books.authorID, authors.author 
FROM books, authors 
WHERE books.authorID = authors.authorID 
        AND (title LIKE '$queryString%' OR author LIKE '$queryString%')LIMIT 5
```

this should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

```
SELECT bk.title, bk.bookID, bk.publisher, bk.pubDate, bk.book_image, bk.authorID, au.author
FROM books bk,  authors au
WHERE bk.authorID = au.authorID AND bk.title LIKE '$queryString%' OR au.author LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 5
```